# WKWebsiteDataStore.remove(...) not removing web site data in iOS10

Tags: ios, webkit

I've been trying to clear all website data before loading up a website into a `WKWebView` and it doesn't appear to be working. Here is the code I've been playing with to try and figure this out:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
    let allTypes = WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()

    print("Reading cached data ...")
    dataStore.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: allTypes) { records1 in

        print("Clearing web data \(records1)") // Should show old website data
        dataStore.removeData(ofTypes: allTypes, for: records1) {

            print("Reading data store after clear ...")
            dataStore.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: allTypes) { records2 in

                print("Data store after clear \(records2)") // Should be empty, but isn't

                print("Reading web data from new configuration ...")
                let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
                let dataStore2 = webConfiguration.websiteDataStore
                dataStore2.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: allTypes) { records3 in

                    print("New config web data \(records3)") // Should be empty, but isn't
                    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
                    self.loadWebsite()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm clearing all data, then inspecting the data store, expecting it to be empty. But it isn't. All the cookies and data is still there as if the remove had not worked. I then load up a completely fresh config and check that, also finding the data still present.

But if I wait a while, or remove the data after the web view has displayed, then but the time I display it again the data is gone.

It almost feels like web kit is queuing the removal of the data and calling it's completion block before it has actually occurred.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
let cacheTypes = Set<String>([WKWebsiteDataTypeDiskCache, WKWebsiteDataTypeMemoryCache])
let store = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()

store.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: cacheTypes) { (record) in
    store.removeData(ofTypes: cacheTypes, for: record){ }
}
```